# How to add toolbar on frontend in fof

Tags: joomla-3.x, fof

I am trying to create vendor panel.

And I need to show Toolbar on frontend.

I read the documentation and I created `toolbar.php`.

Help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find more information about FOF Toolbar here:

## The Toolbar

https://github.com/akeeba/fof/wiki/The-Toolbar